# Using Native Module in an Expo Project in a 'Managed apps'?

Tags: react-native, expo

So the post is with reference to article

https://blog.expo.io/you-can-now-use-expo-apis-in-any-react-native-app-7c3a93041331

The 'Managed apps' here refers to an app created using `expo-cli`. I was wondering if one could implement one's own native module in a 'Managed App';

The app does run with `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`, so do we get all the functionality of a normal react-native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the article that you shared says:

> You can now use Expo APIs in any React Native app

Which means that you can use the Expo APIs, but in 'Bare' workflow.
It doesn't say that you can work with native modules in 'Managed' workflow.
Bare workflow means that you cannot use the following Expo services:

- The build service (expo build:ios; expo build:android)
- Expo publish
- over-the-air (OTA) updates
- Push notifications

Comment: So here's the thing i have a simple react-native app (i.e app created using reac-native init) and the app uses native modules,  i have not published it yet. I want to use  the print package provided as a uni-module. Now, i can either add print as a uniModule to my project or create a new project using expo init and copy the entire code in the new project which as of today can be done. In case i choose the latter will the native modules i have implemented work ?

Comment: This article gives the instructions: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/bare/hello-world/

Comment: Hmmm.. sure i will give it a try.

Comment: So here is a link `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@unimodules/core`, maybe i'm not getting it but what is this for ?

Comment: Seems that they uploaded their repo to npm... That you use when you work in bare workflow with their APIs.